# How can I create a TRIGGER in MySQL from this Oracle syntax?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I'm teaching myself RDMSs through a text book. I'm used to using MySQL so I'm sticking to it, but the book uses Oracle.

I'm trying to create a trigger in MySQL with the Oracle command

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF P_ONHAND ON PRODUCT
BEGIN
    UPDATE ON PRODUCT
        SET P_REORDER = 1
        WHERE P_ONHAND <= P_MIN;
END;
/
```

When I run the above, I get

> `Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF P_ONHAND ON PRODUCT'`

Basically in the `PRODUCT` table, if an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` is made, and the quantity on-hand (`P_ONHAND`) is less than the product minimum (`P_MIN`), a flag should be raised on `P_REORDER`.

I'm not sure how to go about putting this into MySQL syntax without separating the `INSERT OR UPDATE`, which would break the requirement of the command. Is this even possible in single `TRIGGER` with MySQL?

This is the best I can think of after going through the MySQL manual

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER;
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.P_ONHAND < P_MIN THEN
            SET P_REORDER = 1;
        END IF;
    END; //
delimiter ;
```

But I still get the error

> `Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   'CREATE TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PRODUCT FOR EACH R' at line 2'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't have `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` triggers in MySQL. Define 2 triggers, one for `AFTER INSERT` and one for `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: @ypercube yea I was starting to figure that after the million different attempts I made. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the MySQL documentation about the **[trigger syntax and examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)**.

You cannot have `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` triggers in MySQL. Define 2 triggers, one for `INSERT` and one for `UPDATE`. Another limitation is that `AFTER` triggers cannot change the updated rows, so you can use `BEFORE` triggers. Like this:

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER_BEFORE_INSERT ;
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCT_REORDER_BEFORE_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.P_ONHAND < NEW.P_MIN THEN
            SET NEW.P_REORDER = 1;
        END IF;
    END; //
delimiter ;
```

and similarly for the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger